# why have multiple image sizes

Tags: android, bitmap, image-scaling

I am trying to understand the reason for having multiple image sizes.  I know there are different size screens with different densities, but wouldn't it be acceptable to just have the largest resolution image and load it to the size you need rather than have lots of different images?

Comment: you can do that place large images in default folder :D /drawable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaling an image takes considerably more processing power than just loading a pre-rendered one. Also, a naive/simple image scaling algorithm would look pretty low quality compared to one that had been actually properly rendered at the right size in the first place.

Comment: An image scaling algorithm can be both acceptable quality and fast. I was doing this back in the days of 25Mhz processors.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't possible, my point stands: it's still more processing than simply loading the right sized image in the first place, and won't be as good quality as creating the image at the right size or for example a bicubic resample in Photoshop.

Comment: I think we agree that resizing will be slower and lower quality than loading a premade image. The question was "wouldn't it be acceptable", and I contend that it would be. I know from experience that it can be fast enough and high enough quality at the same time if you use the proper algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You *could*, I suppose, but what about

- Bandwidth
- Size of original image
- Computational overhead

Answer (score 0):

You are right it is acceptable.
As always this is just about trading speed for disk space.
You decide if you increase the size or have your graphics resize at runtime... it depends on your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you do not have to be processiing a long file over and over again, imagine lots of visitors onto your site all of them requesting the same image they have different resolutions is better to have different images instead being processing the largest image to have a new one for each request, this is because of performance on the server side with an important concurrency in your site this may carry issues for the Heap Space you must care about data process performance. some times you have to choose in between resources Heap Space, Processor and DataSpace.